# How do I remove connecting lines for non sequential dates in a time series plot using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am plotting several sets of sensor data on a time series plot using the Highcharts javascript library. Each point is a tuple of day (timestamp) and a sensor reading value. On some occasions there are holes in the data due to sensor failure. I want to interconnect data points with a line only when the data points are sequential days.

Comment: When you are missing some of dates, then set for that points `null` as value.

Comment: That would require iterating through all of the series and looking for missing dates. I hoped there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you are using Highstock, then consider [gapSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.gapSize) option. In Highcharts you need to put null values.

Comment: any solution involves looping through the data and identifying missing dates - whether you do it or the library does it, level of elegance doesn't change :)